# how to trigger edittext OnEditorActionListener on emulator(hardware keyboard enabled)?

Tags: android, android-emulator

how to trigger edittext OnEditorActionListener(IME_ACTION_SEARCH) on emulator(hardware keyboard enabled). any one can help me.

i tried enter key. it's not work.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this solution and it worked for me.

```
YourEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId,
                KeyEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Pressed",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: but i want search option